# EPOC date to Normal system date in VBS

Tags: datetime, vbscript, date-format, epoch

I have read many post but nothing really helped.
My question looks similar but bit different.

I have to change EPOC time to system time format.

```
data type = datetime
value= 20160630165419.634204+060
```

desired output 
data type = datetime

```
value= 30/06/2016 16:54:19
```

as the EPOC value has digits after dot and the datatype is datetime , which makes it difficult to divide it by 10 in a loop and get ingteral value. 
Please suggest solution for given input format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function `WMIDateStringToDate` for converting your date :

```
WScript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("20160227235343.000000+060")
WScript.echo WMIDateStringToDate("20160630165419.634204+060")
'************************************************************
Function WMIDateStringToDate(Mydate)
 WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(Mydate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
 Mid(Mydate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(Mydate, 4) _
 & " " & Mid (Mydate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
 Mid(Mydate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(Mydate,13, 2))
End Function
'************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: use [DateSerial()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [TimeSerial()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3e7s5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on numbers ([CInt(](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx))) extracted from your input ([Mid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) to get a variant of subtype Date

Step 2: use [SetLocale()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf99h19%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to format/stringify the Date

```
>> SetLocale "de-de"
>> sX = "20160630165419.634204+060"
>> dtD = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(sX, 1, 4)), CInt(Mid(sX, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(sX, 7, 2)))
>> dtT = TimeSerial(CInt(Mid(sX, 9, 2)), CInt(Mid(sX, 11, 2)), CInt(Mid(sX, 13,2)))
>> dtX = dtD + dtT
>> WScript.Echo dtX, TypeName(dtX)
>> WScript.Echo Replace(dtX, ".", "/")
>>
30.06.2016 16:54:19 Date
30/06/2016 16:54:19
```

**Danger, Will Robinson!** Look at this test script:

```
Function WMIDateStringToDate(Mydate)
 WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(Mydate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
 Mid(Mydate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(Mydate, 4) _
 & " " & Mid (Mydate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
 Mid(Mydate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(Mydate,13, 2))
End Function
'************************************************************
For Each sLocale In Split("de-de en-us")
    SetLocale sLocale
    For Each sDate In Split("20160227235343.000000+060 20160203235343.000000+060")
      On Error Resume Next
       dtX = WMIDateStringToDate(sDate)
       If Err.Number Then dtX = Err.Description
      On Error GoTo 0
       WScript.Echo GetLocale(), sD, sDate, dtX
    Next
Next
```

and its output:

```
cscript 38249865.vbs
1031  20160227235343.000000+060 27.02.2016 23:53:43
1031  20160203235343.000000+060 02.03.2016 23:53:43
1033  20160227235343.000000+060 27.02.2016 23:53:43
1033  20160203235343.000000+060 03.02.2016 23:53:43
```

to see the reason for:

> The sample scripts are not supported under any Microsoft standard
>   support program or service. The sample scripts are provided AS IS
>   without warranty of any kind. Microsoft further disclaims all implied
>   warranties including, without limitation, any implied warranties of
>   merchantability or of fitness for a particular purpose. The entire
>   risk arising out of the use or performance of the sample scripts and
>   documentation remains with you. In no event shall Microsoft, its
>   authors, or anyone else involved in the creation, production, or
>   delivery of the scripts be liable for any damages whatsoever
>   (including, without limitation, damages for loss of business profits,
>   business interruption, loss of business information, or other
>   pecuniary loss) arising out of the use of or inability to use the
>   sample scripts or documentation, even if Microsoft has been advised of
>   the possibility of such damages.
>   (found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/03a18f58-0e13-47d1-8844-b6821272a914))